# PowerBI API error updating Dataset using Service Principal

Tags: powerbi, service-principal, powerbi-api

**Requirement:** Update PowerBI dataset schedule using Powershell script via a Service Principal. PowerBI API used. Refer: [MicrosoftDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updaterefreshschedule)

**Error Message**:  "Message":"API is not accessible for application"

**What I did:**

1. Provided PowerBI application API permissions in Azure AD. Admin access given to Service Principal in PowerBI workspaces.

   [image: API Permissions]

2. Put the SP in a AD Group. MAde this AD Group the Admin of the Power BI Workspace and Dataset (under Power BI Admin Settings)
3. Used access token generated using Service Principal. Invoke-RestMethod for API request.

   ```
   $SecPasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $ClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
   $ClientCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ClientId,$SecPasswd)

   Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Tenant $tenantId -ServicePrincipal -Credential $ClientCred
   $accessToken = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
   $authHeader = @{'Content-Type'='application/json','Authorization'= $accessToken.Authorization}
   $uri="https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/$datasetId/refreshSchedule"
   Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $authHeader –Method Patch -Body ($jsonBase | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
   ```

**Observations:**

Used datasetId of my workspace and run the script. 2 Scenarios:

1. Using Service Principal access token in Authorization header. Got - `Forbidden 403 Error. "Message":"API is not accessible for application`.
2. When using access token generated with my user credentials in the Authorization header the script runs successfully.
3. Tried various datasets in other workspaces

What permissions am I missing to update the datasets schedule using Service Principal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The URL in the Microsoft API documentation is wrong for service principals.

You need to also include the workspace ID in the URL, see below

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{WorkspaceID}/datasets/{DatasetId}refreshes
```

Answer (score 0):

[Service principal is not supported for accessing **My Workspace**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#considerations-and-limitations):

> **Considerations and limitations**
>
> - Service principal only works with new workspaces.
> - **My Workspace isn't supported when using service principal.**
> - A capacity is required when moving to production.
> - You can't sign into the Power BI portal using service principal.
> - Power BI admin rights are required to enable service principal in developer settings within the Power BI admin portal.
> - Embed for your organization applications can't use service principal.
> - Dataflows management is not supported.
> - Service principal only supports some read-only admin APIs. To enable service principal support for read-only admin APIs, you have to enable the Power BI service admin settings in your tenant. For more information, see Enable service principal authentication for read-only admin APIs.
> - When using service principal with an Azure Analysis Services data source, the service principal itself must have an Azure Analysis Services instance permissions. Using a security group that contains the service principal for this purpose, doesn't work.

You should either move your dataset to a [new workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-create-the-new-workspaces), or change the authentication method.