# calling powerbi api in postman fails

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory, powerbi-custom-visuals, powerbi-api

I'm trying to call the powerbi api for a specific dataset, just to prove to myself that i have security set up correctly.

Ultimately, I will need to make a DAX query from code but to start, i'm using postman to make some basic request to ensure I've set things up correctly.

**What Works**

In the online app (app.powerbi.com), I can do the following (using my user credentials - aka I log in):

[https://app.powerbi.com/groups/{groupid}/datasets/{datasetid}/details?experience=power-bi](https://app.powerbi.com/groups/%7Bgroupid%7D/datasets/%7Bdatasetid%7D/details?experience=power-bi)

This renders my table with all the columns / data.

**What doesn't work**

In postman, i'm trying to retrieve the data from the api like this:

[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupid}/datasets/{datasetid}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7Bgroupid%7D/datasets/%7Bdatasetid%7D)

But when I do, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException",
        "pbi.error": {
            "code": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException",
            "parameters": {},
            "details": [],
            "exceptionCulprit": 1
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to do a POST with a DAX query like this:

[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetid}/executeQueries](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7Bdatasetid%7D/executeQueries)

with a body:

```
{  
  "queries": [  
    {  
      "query": "EVALUATE VALUES('Test Table')"
    }  
  ]  
}
```

But I get the error:

{
"error": {
"code": "PowerBIEntityNotFound",
"pbi.error": {
"code": "PowerBIEntityNotFound",
"parameters": {},
"details": [],
"exceptionCulprit": 1
}
}
}

**Setup**

I have created an application registration in azure called powerbi with the following permissions:

[image]

And then on the actual dataset, i have the following under "sharing"
[image]

**What I've tried so far**

I've searched here on stack and found another post saying that I should decode the JWT token created for my app registration and make sure there's no roles embedded.  I didn't see any field called role(s).

I also tried this request to the api:
[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetid}/refreshes](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7Bdatasetid%7D/refreshes)

```
{
    "Message": "API is not accessible for application"
}
```

and the error I get there is:

**Questions**

In addition to the obvious question of why my calls to the API are failing, I'd like to doublecheck whether or not i need to include "myorg" in the Uris?  Is it supposed to be a literal?  or am i supposed to substitute it with another id? (like group id?).
According to MS's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-dataset-in-group), it seems to be a literal.  Usually, for variables, they use the "{}" syntax to indicate.

What am I missing?  Please and thanks.

Comment: Yes on including `myorg`. In Postman, are you sending any Authorization tokens? See [Power BI REST API: What It Is & How to Use It + Examples](https://blog.coupler.io/power-bi-rest-api/) - see steps 2 & 3.

Comment: @SamNseir yes, i'm generating and sending auth tokens using the app registration i created.  We do this for other code, so i'm pretty sure the auth token we are using is correct.  But happy to double check something / anything if you have specific suggestions

Comment: @SamNseir is myorg supposed to be the literal string, or a variable representing my organization ID?

Comment: `myorg` is literal.

Comment: The error might occur if you missed adding that app registration to your Power BI workspace with Admin/Contributor access. Check similar thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77834978/embedd-power-bi-report-with-free-trial-of-power-bi-pro-license-in-php/77839189#77839189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error occurs if you are using token generated with **client credentials** flow but missed enabling service principal to access your Power BI workspace.

I registered one Entra ID application and granted same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

In my Power BI workspace, I have dataset named **SalesMarketing** like this:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to make below calls, I too got **same errors** as you like this:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupid}/datasets/{datasetid}/
```

**Response:**

[image]

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetid}/refreshes
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to add your  **Entra ID app registration**  to Power BI workspace with  **Admin**  or **Contributor** access.

*Go to Power BI Portal -> Your Workspace -> Click on ... -> Manage access -> +Add people or groups -> Search for Service Principal with name -> Admin*

[image]

In addition to that, you have to allow access for service principals to call Power BI API by **enabling** below option in Admin Portal:

[image]

Now, generate the token again and call below API's where I got **response** successfully like this:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupid}/datasets/{datasetid}/
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, service principal authentication is not supported for accessing **My workspace** (myorg).

In such cases, you need to either change your authentication method to **delegated** flow or use different API calls like this:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupid}/datasets/{datasetid}/refreshes
```

**Response:**

[image]

You need to include **`myorg`** in all URIs and it is a literal that refers to **My Workspace** of your Power BI tenant.

**Reference:**
[PowerBI API error updating Dataset using Service Principal - Stack Overflow by **Neil P** and **Andrey Nikolov**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67259841/powerbi-api-error-updating-dataset-using-service-principal)