How to generate token access Power BI
I am using OAuth to generate bearer token.

The generated token includes "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api" as audience.

But it reports Unauthorized calling Power BI API.
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets


I have already granted the API permissions in app registration.

How to generate access token for Power BI? Please help

Could you confirm whether you added the application in your Power BI workspace or not by granting role to it? Have you enabled service principal access in Admin Portal?

Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77867783/calling-powerbi-api-in-postman-fails/77872076#77872076

Use sp self permission or sp delegate permission ? if sp self permission you should config additional in portal UI.

Note that, client credentials flow comes under service principal authentication which is not supported for accessing My workspace(myorg). To get datasets present in My workspace(myorg), generate token using delegated flows like authorization code flow.
Initially, I registered one application and granted below permissions of Delegated type:

Make sure to add redirect URI in Web platform. I added https://jwt.ms in my case:

Before generating token, run below authorization request in browser that gives code value after successful authentication:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?  
client_id=appId
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope= https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
&state=12345


Now, I generated the token using authorization code flow with below parameters via Postman:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
code:code_from_above_request
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms

Response:

When I used this token to list datasets present in My workspace (myorg), I got the response successfully as below:
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets

Response:

Reference:
Embed Power BI content with service principal and  secret - Power BI | Microsoft
