App Registration error AADSTS500011 show tenant is as domain instead of long string provided
I've tried numerous times to register an app and connect to in in python:
app_id = '670...'
tenant_id = '065...'
client_secret_value = 'YJr...'

import requests
import msal

authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
scopes = ['https://analysis.microsoft.net/powerbi/api/.default']

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(app_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret_value)
result = None
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

Overview:


I feel like I've followed this video exactly:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Fu8FjvYvyc&t=577s&ab_channel=JJPowerBI
I'm up to minute 8:38.
I'm getting the following error messsage and googling it shows me the tenatid should be the id and not the domain name. I'm not sure why that's happening and what I need to change to get this to work

Edit adding API Permissions
I am the owner of the subscription.



Edit2: Looks a little different then the comment, but I enabled this and it says it could take 15 minutes to update.


Could you include API permissions Portal image of your app registration by editing your question?

@Sridevi added the pictures

Could you confirm whether you allowed service principal access in your PowerBI Admin portal? Refer this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77867783/calling-powerbi-api-in-postman-fails/77872076#77872076

And please confirm whether you are using any custom domain or tenant domain ending with onmicrosoft.com?

@Sridevi I added another edit. I believe I enabled service principals, says it could take up to 15 minutes to apply change.

@Sridevi I'm not sure how I can confirm customer domain. I haven't picked a redirect url or anything. I really just created the app, added the permissions and secret key.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The error occurred as you are using wrong scope value to generate access token for Power BI API.
Initially, I too got same error when I tried to generate token with scope as https://analysis.microsoft.net/powerbi/api/.default like this:

Make sure to use https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default/ as scope value that worked and generated token successfully as below:
app_id = 'appId'
tenant_id = 'tenantId'
client_secret_value = 'secret'

import msal

authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
scopes = ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default']

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    app_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret_value
)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

if 'access_token' in result:
    print(result['access_token'])
else:
    print(result)

Response:

